# How do I get this powershell script to function from a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to get this powershell to execute from a batch file.

```
ipconfig /all | clip
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = "Insert Email"
$mail.Subject = "My Ip"
$ip = Get-Clipboard
$mail.HtmlBody = '<h1>'+ $ip +'</h1>'
$mail.Display()
$mail.send()
```

The script works in powershell or as a .PS1 file. Other sources have told me to use "powershell" or "powershell -executionpolicy bypass" however neither of these have worked for this. I know this is achievable by using  batch file to run the .PS1 but I'm trying to make this function from a single file download. When I try to put it in a batch file with the aforementioned "powershell" but when I run the batch file it closes strait away and does nothing. Here are the formats in which I have tried these:

```
ipconfig /all | clip
Powershell.exe $ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = "Insert Email"
$mail.Subject = "My Ip"
$ip = Get-Clipboard
$mail.HtmlBody = '<h1>'+ $ip +'</h1>'
$mail.Display()
$mail.send()
```

```
Powershell -executionppolicy bypass ipconfig /all | clip
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = "Insert Email"
$mail.Subject = "My Ip"
$ip = Get-Clipboard
$mail.HtmlBody = '<h1>'+ $ip +'</h1>'
$mail.Display()
$mail.send()
```

I have also tried putting it before each line, non of these have worked.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've attempted, and what, specifically, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Batchscripts are processed one line at a time, so while you can call a Powershell command from within batch, you cannot as far as I can see have it run across multiple lines. It will successfully run the first line as Powershell, but the second line will be handled independently as if it's a normal batch command since it has no concept of how Powershell handles multi-line code.

So if you can write it such that your entire command is within a single line then it is possible. For instance if I take a simple Powershell codeblock

```
$foo = Import-Csv -Path c:\batchscripts\serverlist.csv
$foo2 = $foo | Select -First 3
$foo2 | Export-Csv -Path C:\batchscripts\newcsv2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I can instead successfully run the same code from within a batchscript as

```
powershell.exe -Command "$foo = Import-Csv -Path c:\batchscripts\serverlist.csv; $foo2 = $foo | Select -First 3; $foo2 | Export-Csv -Path C:\batchscripts\newcsv2.csv -NoTypeInformation"
```

with the entire Powershell code enclosed in `""`, and each statement separated by a `;`.

I've seen some mention online of enclosing the code within `{}` rather than `""` but in the above example I found the cmd processor would complain that `$foo2` "is not recognised as an internal or external command", eg it was treating it as a batch command, not as part of the Powershell code. That does mean however you'll need to avoid the uses of `"` within your Powershell code, and stick with `'` instead, though looking at your code I don't think that's likely to cause any issues.